# Building a release (non trunk) version of clang and associated tools

Tags: clang

Apologies if I am missing something obvious, but I have been unable so far to find out how to organize and build clang (+ associated rt libs, etc.) from the source associated with an actual release (e.g. v 7.0.0 released today)

The llvm getting started guide gives good information on how to do this for TRUNK, and I can successfully build per those instructions.

For building from an actual release though, I'm lost right at the start - confused as to where to put contents of the different tar files relative to each other. e.g. where does the content of clang-tools-extra-7.0.0.src.tar.xz go compared to the main llvm dir ?  The content of that tar file shows different paths to various files than is the case with the same files from trunk, so I'm scratching my head a bit.

Is there an equivalent page to https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html , which covers the same steps but for a release version rather than trunk ?

Thanks a lot for any help.
    Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is covered here: [How To Release LLVM To The Public](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToReleaseLLVM.html). Please, see the [Build Clang Binary Distribution](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToReleaseLLVM.html#build-clang-binary-distribution) section.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be how clang developers create and test a binary that is to be put on the binary release page.
What I'm trying to find out is how to build clang for my own use (not as a clang developer) after downloading the sources via tar file fomr the download site.

e.g. there are numerous tar files, and they do not quite map 1-to-1 to the optional components shown for building from trunk ; also the  tar files show different paths than I get with trunk, so it's unclear where I should put the optional extras (rt compiler, extra tools, etc) relative to the llvm dir)